# Matplotlib unexpectedly hidden polygons

Tags: python, debugging, matplotlib, plot

I am using `matplotlib 1.4.3` with `python 3.3`. I would like to draw multiple figures with multiples sub-plot in it. I am facing some kind of bug that is really boring me:

> When I use `fill()` and `boxplot()` methods whithin a figure, results of those functions are hidden if the figure is not the first one created.

This bug seems to be related somehow to polygon display and `matplotlib` environment state.

When a parse only one single figure, everything is working fine. When I parse  multiple figures, the first one is ok. But, in every other subsequent figures, everything is all-right except *wiskerbox* and *polygons* that are hidden.

Each plot code is wrapped into a function, which accepts positional arguments, `*args` and `**kwargs`. Lets say signature are:

```
def myplot(t, x, *args, *kwargs):
    # [...]
    hFig = plt.figure()
    # [...]
    return hFig
```

As far as I understand `python` mechanisms, after the function call is resolved, there must be nothing alive (I do not use global variables) except what `matplotlib` environment has stored into its *global namespace variables*.

In every call, I `close()` my figure, I also have tried `hFig.clf()` in addition before leaving function, but it does not solve the problem.

Each plot is wrapped into printer (decorator) to add generic functionalities:

```
def myprint(func):
     def inner(*args, **kwargs)
          # [...]
          hFig = func(*args, **kwargs)
          # [...]
      return inner
```

What I have tried so far:

- Increased `zscore` of *wiskerbox* and *polygons*, not working;
- Execute plot generation in different *threads*, not working;
- Execute plot generation in different *processes*, working but I have to change my function signature because it can be pickled.

I do not want use `dill` and `pathos`, even if I would I cannot.

It looks like it is a `matplotlib` environment bug, because when I run different processes, this environment is recreated from scratch and it works the way it should. I would like to know if there is a way to reset `matplotlib` environment state within a `python` script. If not, what can I do for solving this issue.

**Obs.:** I am using `GridSpecs` object and `subplot()` method to create my figures. The problem was not present when I computed boxes myself and used `add_axes()` method.

**Update:** Here you can find a MCVE of my problem. By doing this simple example, I found the line which makes my bug happens (looks like I have old bad Matlab behaviours). It seems that `plt.hold(False)` alters the way of *polygons* and `boxplot` are displayed. And, as I pointed out, it was related to matplotlib global namespace variable. I just misunderstood the way this method works, and in each sub-process, it was reset.

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gspec

def bloodyplotit(t_, x_):
    hFig = plt.figure()
    gs = gspec.GridSpec(1, 4, height_ratios=[1], width_ratios=[15, 2, 3, 1])
    gs.update(left=0.10, right=0.90, top=0.90, bottom=0.25, hspace=0.05, wspace=0.05)
    plt.hold(True)
    hAxe = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
    hAxe.plot(t_, x_)
    #plt.hold(False)   # <------------------------ This line make the scirpt bug
    hAxe = plt.subplot(gs[0,1])
    hAxe.hist(x_, orientation='horizontal')
    hAxe = plt.subplot(gs[0,3])
    hAxe.boxplot(x_)
    plt.show()


n = 1000
t = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + np.arange(n)*datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
x = np.random.randn(1000,1)

for i in range(10):
    bloodyplotit(t, x)
```

Comment: can you reduce your problem to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)?

Comment: I will do that this afternoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an even more minimal script that produces the error:

```
x = np.random.randn(1000)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].hold(True)
ax[0].boxplot(x);
ax[1].hold(False)
ax[1].boxplot(x);
```

[image]

As far as I can tell, this is expected behavior. According to the documentation of [`plt.hold`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hold),

> When hold is True, subsequent plot commands will be added to the current axes. When hold is False, the current axes and figure will be cleared on the next plot command.

Boxplot is a compound object: it is created by calling multiple plotting commands. If hold is False, the axes are cleared between each of those commands, so parts of the boxplot don't show up.

Personally, I've never found a reason to toggle the hold state in 10+ years of using matplotlib. My experience is that doing it (especially globally) just causes confusion, and I'd recommend avoiding it.

Comment: Yes this is what I figured out, as I said I was thinking with my Matlab background

Comment: By the way, could you explain how do you gather multiple plots into a single axis without setting hold properties on True?

Comment: Hold is True by default. As long as you don't ever set it to False, you should be fine.